# How to extract Dutch zip code with regex (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

Assume I have the following list:

```
[4486AE Capelle aan de Ijsel, 4706TR Amsterdam]
```

I would like to extract the zip code for each element.

The desired output is:

```
[4486AE, 4706TR]
```

I tried to find a regular expression for Dutch zip codes in Python. However, I only found a JavaScript expression. This is what I tried so far:

```
import re

test = '4706TR Amsterdam'
match =  re.search(r"/^(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})$/i", test)
print(match)
```

This gives me an empty result. Here is where I got the expression from: https://rgxdb.com/r/4W9GV8AC

Anyone has an idea how to solve this? Other SO posts do not focus on Python expression for Dutch zip codes.

Comment: `/^` You don't want to escape that. `^` means start of line, `\^` means match a literal `^` which isn't in your string. Also, why the `\i` after the `$`? `$` means end of line thus you will never match since you want a `\i` after the end of the line.

Comment: Just using `^(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})$` works for me

Comment: Changing the expression to yours still gives me an empty output... match = re.search(r"^(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})$", '4706TR Amsterdam')

Comment: Remove the `^` and `$` since you aren't matching the whole line: `(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})`

Comment: Try `(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})(?!P.*)`

Comment: I suggest having a look at a [tutorial that teaches you the basics](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html). Knowing the basics of regex is more useful than you might realize. You'll find use of this knowledge in almost every language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `/^(?:NL-)?(\d{4})\s*([A-Z]{2})$/i` has a Javascript notation.

The leading and trailing `/` are the pattern delimiters, `^` and `$` are the anchors to assert the start and end of the string and the `/i` flag is for a case insensitive match.

In Python, to get the match in your question you can match 4 digits and 2 uppercase chars A-Z between word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial matches instead of using the anchors as the matches are not the only string.

The case insensitive matches can be done using `re.IGNORECASE`

Using re.search can also return None, so first check if re.search has a value and then use `.group()` to get the match.

```
import re

test = '4706TR Amsterdam'
match =  re.search(r"\b\d{4}[A-Z]{2}\b", test, re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

Output

```
4706TR
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JIlZBo)

If you want to match an optional `NL-` part, the pattern can be:

```
\b(?:NL-)?\d{4}[A-Z]{2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHjAYK/1)

Comment: Great answer. `re.IGNORECASE` is also aliased as [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) for those preferring a more compact version.

Comment: I forgot `\b` was a thing. This is a much better answer.